# Test whether $f$ is constant or not.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let , $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ be continuous and $f(x^2)=f(x)$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. Then which are TRUE ?

(A) $f$ is a constant function.

(B) $f$ is differentiable function.

(C) $f$ is uniformly continuous.

(D) $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.

As the domain $[0,1]$ is compact so the function $f$ is uniformly continuous.

But I am unable to test the other options..Please help.

Comment: $(A)$ is true. To show it, start with any $x<1$ and use the hypothesis repeatedly

Comment: This reminds of another Q that came up 2 day ago: If f is analytic on the open complex unit disk $D$  and $f(x)=f(2 x)$, then  prove $f$ is constant on $D$. After some complicated answers (including mine), it was noted that  if  $f$ is continuous  at $0$ and $f(x)=f(2 x)$, then $f(z)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f(2^{-n}z)=f(0).$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:
For an arbitrary $x\in ]0,1[$, you have that $f(x)=f(x^2)=f(x^4)=f(x^8)=\ldots$. What is the limit of the sequence $x^{2^n}$ ? What can you deduce from that ?

Answer (score 1):

D is not true. You could have $f(x) = c$ for some negative constant $c$. That would satisfy the conditions.

C is also true, since $f$ is continuous.

A is true. Note that $f(x) = f(x^2)$ for $x = \{0, 1\}$ since $0^2 = 0$ and $1^2 = 1$, but not for any other values. It's possible to construct a piecewise function to take multiple values, but then $f$ would not be continuous. Consequently, $f$ must be constant -- i.e. $f(x) = c$ for some constant $c$.

B is true. A constant function is differentiable.